# html form post in laravel 5.5.1 cant get the right routes

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to insert data into the db, however i can't get the routing to work properly , not able to verify nor can post the form using the controller. i keep getting error for invalid routing, tried almost everything to solve but wasn't able to. Thanks

controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SellauthController extends Controller
{

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
         return Validator::make($data, [
            'storename' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'city3' => 'required|string|min:5|max:100',
            'storelocation' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'pannumber' => 'numeric',
            'vatnumber' => 'numeric',
            'productcat' => 'required|string|max:255',
         ]);
    }
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $userid = (!Auth::guest()) ? Auth::user()->id : null ;
        return Sellauths::create([
            'userid' => $userid,
            'storename' => $data['store-name'],
            'storelocation' => $data['city3'].$data['store-location'],
            'pannumber' => $data['store-pan'],
            'vatnumber' =>  $data['store-vat'],
            'productcat' => $data['store-product-types'],
            'active' => 0,
        ]);
        return User::update([
            'usercat' => 'sells',
        ]);
    }

}
```

**view / form**

```
<form class = "seller-reg-form" action="{{url('member/dashboard/sellregistered')}}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <h3 class = "in-page-title" > Register as a seller  </h3>
    :
    :
</form>
```

model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class sellauth extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;

        protected $fillable = [
            'userid','storename', 'storelocation', 'pannumber', 'vatnumber', 'productcat', 'usercat', 'blocksell', 'active'
        ];
}
```

Route::prefix('member')->group(function () {

```
// subpage to create a post found at /admin/posts/create (app/views/admin/posts-create.blade.php)

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('layouts.controlpanel')->with('pg', 'dashboard');    
});

Route::get('/dashboard', function()
{
    return View::make('layouts.controlpanel')->with('pg', 'dashboard');            
});

Route::get('/dashboard/sellregister', function(){
    return View::make('layouts.controlpanel')->with('pg', 'sellregister');
});

Route::post('/dashboard/sellregistered', 'SellauthController');
/*
function(){
    return redirect('member/dashboard/sellregister')->with('status', 'Successfully Submited');    
});
```

*/

```
route::auth();
```

});

Comment: Can you provide more detail in what you're attempting?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to post the route code, i am trying to insert data into db first by validating and inserting,but i am not able to make a successful route. according to error in the browser.

Comment: Ok i have found that my methods in the controller are protected, made a new controller with public method... it routing now!! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answered

Ok i have found that my methods in the controller are protected, made a new controller with public method... its routing now!! Thanks :-)